# Column name as parameter and do sum on that in T Sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

My requirement is to send Columnname as Parameter to Stored procedure and do SUM on that Column.

I have written a small stored procedure to accept the column name as a parameter and do sum on that but I am getting an error with it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testCol
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @type as nvarchar(20),
    @beginDate as smalldatetime,
    @endDate as smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here


        select dbo.mytable.date, sum(@type) as quantity 
        from dbo.mytable
            where dbo.mytable.Date between @beginDate AND @endDate
        group by dbo.mytable.date,dbo.mytable.day 
        order by dbo.mytable.date
END
GO
```

I am getting the error as `"Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator."`  while executing this stored procedure.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use dynamic sql to get the passed column name to be used this way in the query.

Use **sp_executesql** and include the column name in the string, and pass @beginDate and @endDate as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there no other way than using dynamic sql? Because I want to avoid it.

Comment: See SqlACID's answer.  That's a way to avoid it (using CASE if you know all of the columns that might be passed as parameters).

Comment: By the way, to avoid SQL Injection you could verify that what they pass is, indeed, a column in your table.  Maybe testing the condition:

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.mytable','U') AND [name] = @type)

Comment: Also, when you add it to the string, be sure to surround it by square brackets (i.e. '[' + @type + ']') as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the column names that are valid values, you can use CASE to avoid the evils of [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx):

```
  select dbo.mytable.date, 
         sum(case @type when 'QuantityColumn1' then QuantityColumn1 
                         else QuantityColumn2 end ) as quantity  
        from dbo.mytable 
            where dbo.mytable.Date between @beginDate AND @endDate 
        group by dbo.mytable.date,dbo.mytable.day  
        order by dbo.mytable.date
```

If you must resort to dynamic SQL, [validate](http://xkcd.com/327/) your input so it can be trusted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I dont know all the values that going to be there for my column, so I cannot use case statement here. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is an easier way, Coolcake.  Just cast the variable first like so:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO
(N VARCHAR(20))

SELECT * FROM DBO.FOO
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES('10')
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES('20')
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES('30')
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES('40')
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES('50')

SELECT SUM(CAST(N AS INT)) FROM FOO
```

Comment: This is not what is being asked. The OP is trying to pass a column *name* as a parameter to an aggregate function. The `nvarchar` referred to in the error message is that name. So it is not about some number or numbers stored as `nvarchar` as you seem to have assumed.